# Finding a Counter Example - Limits of integrals of an increasing sequence of Borel measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, limits, measure-theory

I need to find a counter example to the following problem. I'm trying to think of some, but maybe I'm not creative. I'm not sure.

Let $h$ and $h_1, h_2, h_3, ...$ be Borel measurable functions such that $h_n \uparrow h$. Then

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_\Omega h_n d\mu = \int_\Omega h d\mu                       $$

Comment: What do you mean by $h_n\uparrow h$? One definition could be your integral limit for example, in which case you cannot possibly find a counter-example.

Comment: By $h_n \uparrow h$ I mean $(h_n)$ is an increasing sequence that converges to $h$.

Comment: If at least one of the $h_n$ is integrable (let us say $h_1$ is integrable for simplicity), you can apply the monotone convergence theorem to $h_n -h_1$ to show that the statement you want to disprove is true. Hence, your example will have to satisfy $\int h_n =-\infty$ for all $n$ (the case $\int h_n =\infty$ is trivial). I leave it to you to find the actual example.

Comment: @DmitriValentine - yes, but increasing in what sense? Pointwise?If it is in the sense that $\int_{\Omega }^{}h_nd\mu >\int_{\Omega }^{}h_{n-1}d\mu$ then you cannot find a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by $h_n\uparrow h$ you mean that $h_n$ is an increasing sequence of functions that converge pointwise to $h$. Provided $h$ is integrable then we always have:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\Omega}h_nd\mu=\int_{\Omega}hd\mu$$

by the [Dominated Convergence Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem), i.e. no counter examples exist.